# Circle explosion from center of canvas

Tags: java, graphics

I have a canvas set up and i am trying to figure out an equation to make circles appear starting at the origin and then in random locations with increasing boundaries.  I drew this image in paint to help explain what i want to happen[image: cirlce appear][image: loop]

This is the loop to draw two explosions from top right and top left corners:

```
for (iii = 0; iii <= 6000; iii++)
{

    graphics.setColor(colors[c1]);//same color as comet

    a1 = ((int)(Math.random() * iii/10));
    a2 = ((int)(Math.random() * iii/10 ));
    a3 = ((int) (Math.random()* 15 + 1));
    graphics.drawOval(a1, a2, a3, a3);

    graphics.setColor(colors[c2]);//same color as comet

    a2 = ((int)(Math.random() * iii/10 ));
    a1 = 600 - ((int)(Math.random() * iii/10));

    a3 = ((int) (Math.random()* 20 + 1));
    graphics.drawOval(a1, a2, a3, a3);
    try 
    {
        TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1);///change to higher #
    } // end try
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Exception caught");
    } // end catch
```

here is the picture of that : [image: 0,0 to 600,600 and 600,0 to 0, 600]

im not asking for someone to write the code for me, i just cannot figure out how to go about it and could use a little nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
a1 = screenWidth - (int)((Math.random()-0.5)*iii/10);
...
graphics.drawOval(a1-a3/2, a2-a3/2, a3, a3);
```

Comment: that started at the top right and drew circles increasing right and down

Answer (score 0):

heres what I ended up doing:

```
for (iii = 0; iii <= 6000; iii++)
            {
                //random sized, random colored circles explosion
                c3 = ((int)(Math.random()*8));
                graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                a1 = 300-iii/10 +(2*((int)(Math.random()*iii)))/10;//x coordinate
                a2 = 300-iii/10 +(2*((int)(Math.random()*iii)))/10;//y coordinate
                a3 = ((int) (Math.random()* 15 + 1));   //size (length = width)
                graphics.fillOval(a1, a2, a3, a3);      //center of circle black
                graphics.setColor(colors[c3]);          //randomly selected color
                graphics.drawOval(a1, a2, a3, a3);      //outline of circle

                try 
                {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3);
                } // end try
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception caught");
                } // end catch

            }//end for center explosions
```

[image: frame1][image: frame2][image: frame3]

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void explosion(final float XCenter, final float YCenter, final int rad) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i <= rad; i++) {
                int degree = rand.nextInt(359);
                int x = XCenter + (float) (Math.cos(degree * 3.141592 / 180) * i);
                int y = YCenter + (float) (Math.sin(degree * 3.141592 / 180) * i);
                int size = ((int) (Math.random() * 15 + 1));
                int color = Color.rgb(rand.nextInt(254), rand.nextInt(254), rand.nextInt(254));
                graphics.setColor(color);         
                graphics.drawOval(x, y, size, size);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this would solve user's problem?